# Only last row of Datagridview updated error

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have to update a Dataridview by using the following code:

```
private void tbrSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(strConStr);
        sqlConn.Open();

            var cmdUpdate = new SqlCommand("proc_TBL_PROC_PN_Update", sqlConn);
            cmdUpdate.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow item in grdProcess.Rows)
            {
                if (!item.IsNewRow)
                {
                    cmdUpdate.Parameters.Clear();
                    cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_PROCESS_INST_NO", txtInstNo.Text);
                    cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_PROCESS_CONTENTS", item.Cells[4].Value);
                    cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_PROCESS_DATE", item.Cells[5].Value);
                    cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_DELIVERY_DATE", item.Cells[6].Value);
                    cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_OPT_MACHINE_NAME", item.Cells[7].Value);
                    cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        sqlConn.Close();
        sttlblMessage.Text = "Data has been updated successfully.";

    }
    catch
        (Exception ex)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

But only all rows of this DataGridview row were updated with the same value of the last row

Here is the input data:

[image]

After click Save button it will be :

[image]

And this is my SQL sp:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_TBL_PROC_PN_Update]
    @_PROCESS_INST_NO nvarchar(50),
    @_PROCESS_CONTENTS  nvarchar(50),
    @_PROCESS_DATE nvarchar(50),
    @_DELIVERY_DATE nvarchar(50),
    @_OPT_MACHINE_NAME nvarchar(50)     
AS
    UPDATE [ENVNDIVDB].[dbo].[TBL_PROC_PN] SET _PROCESS_CONTENTS=@_PROCESS_CONTENTS,_PROCESS_DATE=@_PROCESS_DATE,  _DELIVERY_DATE = @_DELIVERY_DATE,_OPT_MACHINE_NAME=@_OPT_MACHINE_NAME
    WHERE _PROCESS_INST_NO=@_PROCESS_INST_NO
```

And here is the correct result:

[image]

Comment: Could it be that txtInstNo.Text has always the same id?

Comment: Yes, it is the same number for a Process of a Purchase Order

Comment: So you are updating the same record all the time? So you will always update to the value of the last row (the last query you execute).

Comment: please see my update picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The six rows have all the same *_PROCESS_INST_NO* so the UPDATE changes all the 6 rows at each loop. You end up with all rows containing the values of your last loop (the last grid row).

To update a single record, you need the LINE_NO parameter provided in the same table to distinguish from the six rows with the same _PROCESS_INST_NO.

The first thing to change is the SP to receive the LINE_NO parameter and use it in the where statement

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_TBL_PROC_PN_Update]
    @_PROCESS_INST_NO nvarchar(50),
    @_PROCESS_CONTENTS  nvarchar(50),
    @_PROCESS_DATE nvarchar(50),
    @_DELIVERY_DATE nvarchar(50),
    @_OPT_MACHINE_NAME nvarchar(50),
    @_LINE_NO nvarchar(50)     
AS
    UPDATE [ENVNDIVDB].[dbo].[TBL_PROC_PN] 
         SET _PROCESS_CONTENTS=@_PROCESS_CONTENTS,
             _PROCESS_DATE=@_PROCESS_DATE,  
             _DELIVERY_DATE = @_DELIVERY_DATE,
             _OPT_MACHINE_NAME=@_OPT_MACHINE_NAME
    WHERE _PROCESS_INST_NO=@_PROCESS_INST_NO 
      AND _LINE_NO = @_LINE_NO
```

Then change you code to pass the parameter for the _LINE_NO field

```
    if (!item.IsNewRow)
    {
        cmdUpdate.Parameters.Clear();
        cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_PROCESS_INST_NO", txtInstNo.Text);
        cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_LINE_NO", item.Cells[3].Value);
        cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_PROCESS_CONTENTS", item.Cells[4].Value);
        cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_PROCESS_DATE", item.Cells[5].Value);
        cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_DELIVERY_DATE", item.Cells[6].Value);
        cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_OPT_MACHINE_NAME", item.Cells[7].Value);
        cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Note also that your parameters are all of type string. This could be a problem if some conversion to the real data type required by your database doesn't work as you expect (dates for example are a well known source of problem with this pattern). Use always parameters of the correct datatype and do [not use AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Another minor optimization is to move the creation of the parameters outside the loop without adding a value for them. Inside the loop you don't need to clear and re-add every parameter at each loop, but you could simply change the Value with the row cell value and reuse the parameter until the end of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a Primary Key to your table (a unique index) and use that to identify your record.

Your query:

```
UPDATE [ENVNDIVDB].[dbo].[TBL_PROC_PN] SET _PROCESS_CONTENTS=@_PROCESS_CONTENTS,_PROCESS_DATE=@_PROCESS_DATE,  _DELIVERY_DATE = @_DELIVERY_DATE,_OPT_MACHINE_NAME=@_OPT_MACHINE_NAME
WHERE _PROCESS_INST_NO=@_PROCESS_INST_NO
```

Is saying "update these fields where the row _PROCESS_INST_NO = 79680" and all your records have the same value in that field, so your query will affect all records and that's why you have the last value of the foreach in all of them.

Once you have a primary key then change your foreach to use it:

```
cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", item.Cells[0].Value);
cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_PROCESS_CONTENTS", item.Cells[4].Value);
cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_PROCESS_DATE", item.Cells[5].Value);
cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_DELIVERY_DATE", item.Cells[6].Value);
cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_OPT_MACHINE_NAME", item.Cells[7].Value);
```

And of course change your query to use the primary key too:

```
UPDATE [ENVNDIVDB].[dbo].[TBL_PROC_PN] SET _PROCESS_CONTENTS=@_PROCESS_CONTENTS,_PROCESS_DATE=@_PROCESS_DATE,  _DELIVERY_DATE = @_DELIVERY_DATE,_OPT_MACHINE_NAME=@_OPT_MACHINE_NAME WHERE Id=@Id
```

Comment: the problem is this Table is desiged by other people and it had a lot of data. They wrote this application by VB6 , but they can update the grid. Now I must use the old table structure but using c#. Any way? Why they can update this datagridview with this duplicated INDEXNO?

Comment: If you can't modify the table to add a PK, then use the solution proposed by @Steve, just make sure the combination of _PROCESS_INST_NO and _LINE_NO is unique.